# PrimeFaces Extension <pe:keyFilter> Javascript Error

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions, keyfilter

I am using `<pe:KeyFilter/>` , and, when I run my project in IE8, the following error is shown.

**'b.browser.safari' is null or not an object         keyfilter.js.seam?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=1.1.0, line 1 character 219**.

When I debug **keyfilter.js** file, error is show "**d=b.browser.safari?e[d]||d:d**" at that place.

I already added

1. primefaces-4.0.jar
2. primefaces-extensions-1.1.0.jar
3. commons-lang3-3.1.jar
   in my project.

And I have already declared

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in web.xml.

And in my xhtml page,
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions

```
<p:inputText value="#{LoginFormBean.loginHeaderBean.day}" name="day" id="day">
    <pe:keyFilter mask="num" /> 
</p:inputText>
```

How can I solved this problem? Please give me suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it can be helpful for someone else =)

Try to add a 'p:panel' before 'pe:keyfilter' :

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <p:panel />
</div>
<p:inputText value="#{LoginFormBean.loginHeaderBean.day}" name="day" id="day">
    <pe:keyFilter mask="num" /> 
</p:inputText>
```

I had the same issue but I fixed it that way.
If anyone knows a better solution, would be nice to know it.

Hope it helps.

thanks.